# Is it possible to use images passed down from context_dict in background-image property? Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, image

I'm trying to access an image passed down from context dictionary in a Django template as a background-image, like this:

```
<div style="background-image:url('{{city.city_image.url}}');">
```

But it doesn't seem accessible from HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 0):

After looking further, it can be achieved like this:

```
<div style="background-image:url('{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{city.city_image}}');">
```